# How to install Java on Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, java

I am a new Mac user. I need to install Java on my Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What situation makes you think Java is missing? Is there something that does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Java comes already installed. It should be: /usr/bin/java

What makes you think it is missing?

Answer (score 1):

and you can configure java with "Java Preferences.app" located in /Applications/Utilities

Answer (score 1):

Java is already installed on Mac.

Open Terminal from `/Applications/Utilities/` and type `java -version`. You should see something like this:

```
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248-10M3025)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)
```

If appears `-bash: java: command not found`, ore anything else, please write below comments for further instructions.